# These three people are connected, How so?

Tags: knowledge

> Sally just started a game of checkers with Susan.
>
> Dave's back is against the wall and there is no where to run.
>
> Adam is a really popular Australian animal.

How are Sally, Dave, and Adam connected?

**EDIT**

**Hint 1**

> just saying, Adam is probably an emu or kangaroo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

None of the three

> can go backwards.

Sally's pieces, being in a new game,

> have not been kinged yet. As such, they can only move forward.

With Dave's back against a wall,

> he too cannot go backwards.

Adam, being probably an emu or a kangaroo, is one of the two animals which support the Australian coat of arms, both chosen to represent the progress of the country

> by the fact that they never go backwards.

Hence, Sally, Dave, and Adam are connected by the fact that

> none of them can go backwards.

Comment: Good Job! you got it.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps...

> ...they all have to do with hopping/jumping? In checkers, pieces hop over each other; if one is trapped by a wall, one's only way to escape is to [hop the wall](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=safari&rls=en&ei=1HMqXOGKMZTW9AO2urb4Cw&q=wall%20hop&oq=wall%20hop&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i10i19j0i19l2j0i10i19j0i19l4j0i22i30i19l2.10096.11530..11746...0.0..0.144.1104.0j8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i71j0i67j0i10.X-nhjavwbhQ); kangaroos are Australian animals that are well-known because they hop.

Comment: Close, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is so out of left field, but

> The Calgary Stampede? Sally is a reference to a Dolly Parton song. Dave is a reference to a Seether song. Adam is a reference to a Twenty One Pilots album. All three bands headlined the Stampede.

Comment: Very out of left field lol.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think:

> Adam is probably trapped in a cage and he has nowhere to go. At least one of Sally and Susan’s checkers will have nowhere to go sometime in the game. And Dave has nowhere to run (go).

Comment: I like your reasoning, but nope.